# Cannot invoke '*' with an argument list of type '' - Issue with Swift Generics

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

I have a generic method which accepts an array of UITableviewCells to register for a tableView. When I try to register the get the below error

***Cannot invoke 'register' with an argument list of type '(nibs: [UITableViewCell.Type])'***

All the UITableviewCells I am trying to register are conforming to a protocol named `ReusableCell`

**The Protocol goes as follows:**

```
 protocol ReusableCell: class { static var identifier: String { get }}

 extension ReusableCell where Self: UIView {
        static var identifier: String {
            return String(describing: self)
        }
    }
```

**The Generic method goes as follows:**

```
extension UITableView {
func register<T: UITableViewCell>(nibs: [T.Type]) where T: ReusableCell {
        nibs.forEach { register($0.self, cellName: $0.identifier) }
    }
}
```

**My Implementation goes as follows:**

```
class CellOne: UITableViewCell, ReusableCell {}

class CellTwo: UITableViewCell, ReusableCell {}

tableView.register(nibs: [CellOne.self, CellTwo.self])
```

- This above line pops an error 'Cannot invoke 'register' with an argument list of type '(nibs: [UITableViewCell.Type])''

**---Edited---**

But the same function doesn't throw any error if both cells are of the same class

```
tableView.register(nibs: [CellOne.self, CellOne.self])
```

What am I missing here? Any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the generic register function an extension on UITableView?

Comment: yes it is in the UITableview extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need generics for this. You can just use `ReusableCell.Type`. You also don't need `$0.self` since `$0` is already a `Type`

```
extension UITableView {
    func register(nibs: [ReusableCell.Type])  {
        nibs.forEach { self.register($0, forCellReuseIdentifier: $0.identifier) }
    }
}

class CellOne: UITableViewCell, ReusableCell {}

class CellTwo: UITableViewCell, ReusableCell {}

let tableView = UITableView()

tableView.register(nibs: [CellOne.self, CellTwo.self])
```